# Memory leak in Node.js scraper

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, node.js, screen-scraping

This is a simple scraper written in JavaScript with Node.js, for scraping Wikipedia for periodic table element data. The dependencies are [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) for DOM manipulation and [chain-gang](https://github.com/technoweenie/node-chain-gang) for queuing.

It works fine, most of the time (it doesn't handle errors gracefully), and the code isn't too bad, dare I say for a for attempt, but there is a serious fault with it - it leaks memory horribly, anywhere from 0.3% to 0.6% of the computer's memory for each element, such that by the time it gets to lead it would be using somewhere close to 20%, which is plainly unacceptable.

I've tried working with profilers, but I have either not found them to be helpful or have difficulty interpreting the data. I suspect it has something to do with the way `processElement` gets passed around, but I have difficulty in rewriting the queue code into something more elegant.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    jsdom = require("jsdom"),
    parseUrl = require('url').parse,
    chainGang = require('chain-gang');

var chain = chainGang.create({
    workers: 1
});

var Settings = {
    periodicUrl: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Periodic_table',
    periodicSelector: '#bodyContent > table:first',
    pathPrefix: 'data/',
    ignoredProperties: ['Pronunciation']
};

function writeToFile(output) {
    var keys = 0;

    // Huge nests for finding the name of the element... yeah
    for(var i in output) {
        if(typeof output[i] === 'object' && output[i] !== null){
            for(var l in output[i]) {
                if(l.toLowerCase() === 'name') {
                    var name = output[i][l];
                }
            }

            keys += Object.keys(output[i]).length;
        }
    }

    console.log('Scraped ' + keys + ' properties for ' + name);
    console.log('Writing to ' + Settings.pathPrefix + name + '.json');
    fs.writeFile(Settings.pathPrefix + name + '.json', JSON.stringify(output));
}

// Generic create task function to create a task function that
// would be passed to the chain gang
function createTask (url, callback) {
    console.log('Task added - ' + url);

    return function(worker){
        console.log('Requesting: ' +url);

        jsdom.env(url, [
            'jquery.min.js' // Local copy of jQuery
        ], function(errors, window) {
            if(errors){
                console.log('Error! ' + errors)
                createTask(url, callback);
            } else {
                // Give me thy $
                var $ = window.$;

                // Cleanup - remove unneeded elements
                $.fn.cleanup = function() {
                    return this.each(function(){
                        $(this).find('sup.reference, .IPA').remove().end()
                            .find('a, b, i, small, span').replaceWith(function(){
                                return this.innerHTML;
                            }).end()
                            .find('br').replaceWith(' ');
                    });
                }

                callback($);
            }

            worker.finish();
        });
    }
}

function processElement ($){
    var infoBox = $('.infobox'),
        image = infoBox.find('tr:contains("Appearance") + tr img:first'),
        description = $('#toc').prevAll('p').cleanup(),
        headers = infoBox.find('tr:contains("properties")'),
        output = {
            Appearance: image.attr('src'),
            Description: $('.infobox + p').cleanup().html()
        };

    headers.each(function(){
        var that = this,
            title = this.textContent.trim(),
            rowspan = 0,
            rowspanHeading = '';

        output[title] = {};

        $(this).nextUntil('tr:has(th:only-child)').each(function(){
            var t = $(this).cleanup(),
                headingEle = t.children('th'),
                data = t.children('td').html().trim();

            if(headingEle.length) {
                var heading = headingEle.html().trim();
            }

            // Skip to next heading if current property is ignored
            if(~Settings.ignoredProperties.indexOf(heading)) {
                return true;
            }

            if (rowspan) {
                output[title][rowspanHeading][data.split(':')[0].trim()] = data.split(':')[1].trim();
                rowspan--;
            } else if (headingEle.attr('rowspan')){
                rowspan = headingEle.attr('rowspan') - 1;
                rowspanHeading = heading;

                output[title][heading] = {};
                output[title][heading][data.split(':')[0]] = data.split(':')[1];
            } else if (~heading.indexOf(',')){
                data = data.split(',');

                heading.split(',').forEach(function(v, i){
                    output[title][v.trim()] = data[i].trim();
                });
            } else {
                output[title][heading] = data;
            }
        });
    });

    writeToFile(output);
}

function fetchElements(elements) {
    elements.forEach(function(value){
        // Element URL used here as task id (second argument)
        chain.add(createTask(value, processElement), value);
    });
}

function processTable($){
    var elementArray = $(Settings.periodicSelector).find('td').map(function(){
        var t = $(this),
            atomicN = parseInt(t.text(), 10);

        if(atomicN && t.children('a').length) {
            var elementUrl = 'http://' + parseUrl(Settings.periodicUrl).host + t.children('a:first').attr('href');

            console.log(atomicN, t.children('a:first').attr('href').split('/').pop(), elementUrl);
            return elementUrl;
        }
    }).get();

    fetchElements(elementArray);
    fs.writeFile(Settings.pathPrefix + 'elements.json', JSON.stringify(elementArray));
}

// Get table - init
function getPeriodicList(){
    var elementsList = Settings.pathPrefix + 'elements.json';

    if(path.existsSync(elementsList)){
        var fileData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(elementsList, 'utf8'));
        fetchElements(fileData);
    } else {
        chain.add(createTask(Settings.periodicUrl, processTable));
    }
}

getPeriodicList();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For jQuery-like html processing with node i use now [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) instead of jsdom. So far, i have not seen any memory leaks while scrapping and parsing over 10K pages for a couple of hours.

Comment: This is a good tip. I had some code that tried to parse some html of around 25 megabyte, and jsdom crashed after a LONG delay with an out of memory error. Rewriting the code to use cheerio the code completed in 7 seconds without any errors.

Comment: At the current stage, cheerio is very dissimilar to jQuery and lacks a lot of features in the selectors and DOM wrappers. It's definitely faster, but not compatible, which is an issue if you need the familiarity and expressiveness of jQuery.

Answer (score 24):

jsdom does have a memory leak which stems from the copy in and copy out logic behind node's `vm.runInContext()`.  There has been effort to fix this problem using c++ and we are hoping to prove out the solution before attempting to push it into node.

A workaround for now is to spawn up a child process for each dom and close it down when you are done.

EDIT:

as of jsdom 0.2.3 this issue is fixed as long as you close the window (`window.close()`) when you are done with it.

Comment: window.close() is precisely correct, ensure you're closing out your window once you're done and the GC will work as expected. :)

Comment: If I may : you should include this on the frontpage readme on github. I think its pretty important for the user to know that the window object need to be cleaned! Maybe its "obvious" but for me it wasn't ;) .

Answer (score 4):

I think I have a better work-around, reuse your instance of jsdom by setting the window.document.innerHTML property. Solved my memory leak problems!

```
    // jsdom has a memory leak when using multiple instance
    // cache a single instance and swap out innerHTML
    var dom = require('jsdom');
    var win;
    var useJQuery = function(html, fnCallback) {
        if (!win) {
            var defEnv = {
                html:html,
                scripts:['jquery-1.5.min.js'],
            };
            dom.env(defEnv, function (err, window) {
                if (err) throw new Error('failed to init dom');
                win = window;
                fnCallback(window.jQuery);
            });
        }
        else {
            win.document.innerHTML = html;
            fnCallback(win.jQuery);
        }
    };
    ....
    // Use it!
    useJQuery(html, function($) { $('woohoo').val('test'); });
```

Comment: this didn't really work for me, heres my snippet which works:var jsdom = require('jsdom');
  var win = jsdom.jsdom().createWindow();

  var useJQuery = function(html, fnCallback) {
   jsdom.jQueryify(win, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js", function () {
   win.document.innerHtml = html;
   fnCallback(win);
  });        
    };

Answer (score 0):

I know its not much of an answer but I had a similar problem. I have multiple scrapers running simultaneously and memory was getting leaked.

I have ended up using node-jquery instead of JSDOM

https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery

Comment: Nope, I had actually replaced `node-jquery` with jsdom just now - both leaked memory in a surprisingly similar manner

Comment: Why do you think it's not your code leaking memory? Changing the library probably won't help.