# use node.js to scrape web site on Windows

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

Trying to get jsdom (node.js module) to work on windows.
Keeps complaining about not being built for my node version.

Got node (same version, 0.5.9, from source) installed on a linux machine and node-waffed it.
then i copied it to the windows machine (under node_modules)

Still no go...

Any ideas? or other recommendations for parsing HTML I get from a response to a request I make from node?

Using jquery via jsdom would've been sweet.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say that jsdom (>=0.2.3) currently requires a c++ addon which does not play nice with windows.  I think your best bet would be to try and install jsdom@0.2.1 and work around the memory leak caused by executing javascript in the context of jsdom's window.

Workarounds include:

- spawn a new process per dom
- reuse a window and replace the DOM by way of `document.body.innerHTML = '..new markup..';`

The intention is to move away from the c++ addon, but unfortunately that is not a possibility at this time.

Answer (score 1):

If node.js is not an absolute must, check out [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) by our fellow SO-ist @nrabinowitz. It's tested and proven.

Also, [node-scraper](https://github.com/mape/node-scraper) seems to be the right tool for your job, with 222 watchers and 11 forks it also seems to be pretty active. A use case can be found in the [readme](https://github.com/mape/node-scraper/blob/master/README.md) or [right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718391/memory-leak-in-node-js-scraper).

Comment: OK, I've checked. No go. node-scraper requires contextify, same error

Comment: can't install contextify. it complains that it hasn't been built for my node version (0.5.9 on windows). As there's no node-waf on windows, I've tried installing node 0.5.9 on linux, and downloading contextify and building it, and then transferring it to the node_modules folder on windows, but it's still complaining.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but [node.io has a scraping framework](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/wiki/Scraping) that might fit the bill.

Comment: No Go. Complains about a missing module without even telling me which one it is.

Comment: If you're using windows you need to look at the package.js file and manually download the modules you need to resolve dependencies. Or you can try the experimental version of npm on windows and do npm install ([check the readme](http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html)).

Comment: well, it depends on jsdom, which was the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been playing with the node.js module **Cheerio**, and compared with jsdom, it's:

- Much faster
- Much easier to install
- Much more resilient to broken HTML (compared with jsdom)
- And provides most of the jQuery functions you would use server-side

http://matthewmueller.github.com/cheerio/

---

**Scraping example:**

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://encosia.com', function(error, response, body) {

  // Hand the HTML response off to Cheerio and assign that to
  // a local $ variable to provide familiar jQuery syntax.
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  // Exactly the same code that we used in the browser before:
  $('h2').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text());
  });

});
```