# Memory usage with Node.js, Jsdom, HttpAgent

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

I have made a scrapping script that navigates through a blog in order to get all titles. Problem is that Node is keeping using more and more memory as the script runs (thousands of URLs), until 8 go (max), and then the script crashes.

My script uses loops, there must be a simple way to clear memory?

Here is a code example :

```
var request = require('request'),
httpAgent = require('http-agent'),
jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom,
myWindow = jsdom().createWindow(),
$ = require('jquery'),
jq = require('jquery').create(),
jQuery = require('jquery').create(myWindow),
profiler = require('v8-profiler');

profiler.startProfiling();

request({ uri:'http://www.guylabbe.ca' }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Error when contacting URL')
  }


        var last_page_lk = $(body).find('.pane-content .pager li:last-child a').attr('href');
        var nb_pages = last_page_lk.substring(last_page_lk.indexOf('=')+1);
        var page_lk_base = last_page_lk.substring(0,last_page_lk.indexOf('='));

        var pages = Array();
        pages.push(page_lk_base);
        for(var i=1;i<=nb_pages;i++) {
            pages.push(page_lk_base+'='+i);
        }


        // parser les pages

        var fiches = Array();
        var agent2 = httpAgent.create('www.guylabbe.ca', pages);

        agent2.addListener('next', function (err, agent2) {

            var snapshot = profiler.takeSnapshot();


            $(body).find('.view span.field-content span.views-field-title').each(function(){
                fiches.push($(body).find(this).parents('a').attr('href'));
                //console.log($(body).find(this).html());
            });


            agent2.next();

        });
        agent2.start();

        agent2.addListener('stop', function (agent) {
          console.log('-------------------------------- (fini de cumuler les URL fiches) --------------------------------');

            // Parser les fiches

            var agent_fiches = httpAgent.create('www.guylabbe.ca', fiches);

            agent_fiches.addListener('next', function (err, agent_fiches) {

                console.log('log info');


                agent_fiches.next();

            });
            agent_fiches.start();

            agent_fiches.addListener('stop', function (agent) {
              console.log('-------------------------------- Eh voilà! --------------------------------');
            });

            agent_fiches.addListener('start', function (agent) {
              console.log('-------------------------------- C est parti... --------------------------------');
            });

        });



});
```

Comment: can you share a bit more context, some code?  what library you are using?

Comment: you understand that the more relevant code you post the more accurante answers will be ?

Comment: sorry all I added code example

Answer (score 1):

explicitly null vars where you dont need them anymore. if you create variables outside a closure, and use it inside the closure, you should null it when you dont need it anymore. see this thread and read the accepted answer: [How to prevent memory leaks in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733665/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with jsdom leaking memory.
In my case, closing the jsdom window by doing  solved it.
Maybe you should add `myWindow.close()` after you're done with scraping it.
See related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891729/1824928

Comment: I feel this should have helped but I am a newbie at Node.js and the way my code is written, I couldn't make this work. Thank you very much for your input!